# Checking Client provided Php SID is valid or not?

Tags: php, session, sessionid

For session handling i am using mysql instead of default php file based handling.

so before reading session info from db, i wanted to verify  client provided session id is valid,  i wrote a function and it looks working for now, but still wanted to check with you masters  about it

```
private function validSID($id) {
        return !empty($id) && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9,-]{26,40}$/', $id);
    }
```

Thanks Guys

***EDIT:***
***i did modification as you guys suggested, shown below***

```
private function validSID($id) {
        //make sure the length is 22
    //things are based on   session.hash_bits_per_character = 6
    return preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9,-]{22}$/', $id);
    }
```

Comment: There's no need for that `!empty` call there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking for valid digits, but completely ignoring the fact that PHP's session IDs are a fixed length based on various .ini parameters. You should tailors your check so that any ID string which does NOT match php's current settings should be rejected, e.g. there's [hash_bits_per_character](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-bits-per-character) amongst others.